# Trabajar con radio button con ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic

Saludos comunidad tengo un pequeño problema que no logro resolver los radiobutton en ionic con angular como puedo tomar el valor que contienen estos para guardarlos en un objeto que tengo digase el item of radiolist quiero guardar el value que contiene mi radio button para presentarlo en una ventana pero este no se guarda por medio del ngModel alguna ayuda se lo agradeceria mucho [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El ngModel va en el ion-radio-group:

```
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioSelected">

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of radio_list">
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="{{item.id}}" color="{{item.color}}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Cada vez que se cambies de radio button en radioSelected tendras el value del radio button selecionado.